# ng-click not working in AngularJS, Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova

We are writing an application in Ionic, Cordova, AngularJS.
My code is here https://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/wag7ye4b/1/
My problem is that ui-sref or ng-click is not working as expected. Are there any errors?

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'HomePage.html'

        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl:'templates/HomeScreen.html',
            controller: 'HomePageCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.scan',

          { parent:'app',
            url: '/scan',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Scan.html'
          //  controller: 'SettingsController'
        })
        .state('app.help', {
            url: '/help',
            templateUrl:'templates/Help.html' 
        })
```

In HTML i  have

```
$scope.funOne=function(){
alert("Button Clicked");  };
```

Then this should be called from the html

```
<div>  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><div ng-click="funOne()"><h1> Home Screen</h1> </div>
<div class="centerButton" ng-click="funOne()">
    <a ui-href="app.help"> <img src='assets/img/start_btn.png'/> </a>
    <p>START</p>
</div>
```

ng-click is working from the div which has Home Screen but it is not working on Image. Even ui-sref is not working on the image.

Comment: I think you not defining the dependencies correctly or not including them in you index.html file. Changed a bit and this fiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/wag7ye4b/3/

Comment: It is working in fiddle but not in my setup?

Comment: Yep something might be wrong in ur setup

Comment: But click on heading Home Screen is working. But click on image is not working? Any ideas?

Comment: I resolved the issue it was due to css.

Comment: It is not working due to css But I am unable to resolve the css issues. Can you please help me to resolve same? https://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/wag7ye4b/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the fiddle with the css classes as well changed the ng-click position. Your css is conflicting with the ng-click and hence needs to be at the parent level.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wag7ye4b/9/)

Css Changed:

```
.bar-positive {
    background-color: #C12537;
    border: none;
}
.container {
    width:550px;
    height:550px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;
    display:block;
}
.container .left, .right div p {
    top: 44%;
    left: -14%;
}
.container .right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.rotate div p {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top:27%;
    left:20%;
}
.text {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.container img {
    position:absolute;
}
.rotate img {
    width:100%;
    /*-webkit-transform-origin: 70% 105%;*/
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
}
.rotate {
    width:72%;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    transform-origin: 70% 105%;
    position:absolute;
}
.bottom img {
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);*/
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: 308px;
    margin-left: 141px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.left img {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
.right img {
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);*/
    z-index: -1;
}
.rotate.right div p {
    top:22%;
    left:9%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.rotate.bottom div p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 79%;
    left: 100%;
}
.rotate.left div p {
    top:78%;
    left:26%;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/*New style**/
 .rotate div {
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.flex-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.centerButton img, .centerButton p {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-50%;
    bottom:-50%;
    margin:auto;
}
.centerButton p {
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.centerButton {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-45%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-52%;
    bottom:-50%;
}
```

UPDATE:

Your z-index in the css class was giving the issue. Corrected that in the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wag7ye4b/13/)

CSS for reference:

```
.bar-positive {
    background-color: #C12537;
    border: none;
}
.container {
    width:550px;
    height:550px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    display:block;
}
.container .left, .right div p {
    top: 44%;
    left: -14%;
}
.container .right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.rotate div p {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top:27%;
    left:20%;
}
.text {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.container img {
    position:absolute;
}
.rotate img {
    width:100%;
    /*-webkit-transform-origin: 70% 105%;*/
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
}
.rotate p {
    z-index:9999;
}
.rotate {
    width:72%;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    transform-origin: 70% 105%;
    position:absolute;
}
.bottom img {
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);*/
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top: 308px;
    margin-left: 141px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.left img {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.right img {
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);*/
    z-index: 9999;
}
.rotate.right div p {
    top:22%;
    left:9%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.rotate.bottom div p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 79%;
    left: 100%;
}
.rotate.left div p {
    top:78%;
    left:26%;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/*New style**/
 .rotate div {
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.flex-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.centerButton img, .centerButton p {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-50%;
    bottom:-50%;
    margin:auto;
}
.centerButton p {
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.centerButton {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-45%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-52%;
    bottom:-50%;
}
```

Comment: It is working on outer div but i want seperate function for each petal. Which is not working. Sorry but i am very new to CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/wag7ye4b/10/

Comment: @Sweety: added the updated section your z-index was making the errors. Now the fiddle is working as expected.

Comment: Code i running on web but not on mobile? Any ideas? I dont see same flower like thing on mobile?

Comment: @sweety the img is having margin-top and left in px which is not responsive...add that in percentage and you would be fine. If you think the answer above met your desktop requirements kindly mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I also have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027644/ionic-sub-footer-not-fixed-at-bottom on same platform. Could you please hlep me?