# Ionic sub-footer not fixed at bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I have created a footer and a sub-footer to show parameters. Now my footer stays at bottom but the sub footer is going exactly after the content. Or some times it is going behind content.`<div id="content" ui-view></div>` loads the content and I have used ion-footer.

https://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/wag7ye4b/15/

```
<div class="bar-subfooter" class="bar-assertive"> <div class="modeContainer">
 <div class="mode modeText ">
        <div class="">
         Mode:
         <p> Modulated Mode </p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

```
<ion-footer-bar>

    <div class="bottomcontainer">
            <span class="fontClass">
                Intensity:
                <p> Low </p>
            </span>
             <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                Duration:
             <p> 20 Min </p>
            </span>
            <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                OnTime:
            <p> 10 Sec </p>
            </span>
            <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                OffTime:
                 <p> 10 Sec </p>
            </span>
     </div>
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of sub footer. Actually my implementation was wrong. Sub footer is to be implemented in following way. might be useful for any one else.

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-subfooter" class="bar-assertive">        <div class="modeContainer">    
 <div class="mode modeText ">
        <div class="">
         Mode:
          Modulated Mode 
        </div>     </div>       </div>  </ion-footer-bar>       <ion-footer-bar>

    <div class="bottomcontainer">
            <span class="fontClass">
                Intensity:
                Low
            </span>
             <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                Duration:
              20 Min 
            </span>
            <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                OnTime:
             10 Sec 
            </span>
            <div class="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fontClass">
                OffTime:
                10 Sec 
            </span>
     </div>
```